# Как реализовать открытие layout по нажатию ImageButton (см. рисунки)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ImageButton открывался(появлялся) layout с некоторыми элементами. Как это реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если нужен именно эффект как в whatsapp'е, тогда можете посмотреть данную статью: https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/circular-reveal-effect-like-whatsapp-in-android/ или http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-circular-reveal-effect-like-in-whatsapp.html

Answer (score 1):

BottomSheet [Как вариант, вот пример](https://habr.com/post/309200/)

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял:

```
private MyLayout myLayout;

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    swich (id) {
        case R.id.imageButton:
            myLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myLayout.startAnimation(/*нужная анимация*/);
            break;
    }
}
```